# Is there any good command to get pixel's gray value (in this case I'm working on a gray image)

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation, variance

I found img.getpixel((i,j))[0] that works well, but I want to pick the gray value of pixels that have less gray value than T (T go grom 0 to 255). I tried the code below but it didn't work as I expected.

```
#create a list to store results for each loop:
J={}
#picking gray value of pixels:
totalgrayvalue=0
for i in range (width):
    for j in range (height):
        for T in range (255):
            if totalgrayvalue == (im_grey.getpixel((i,j)))[0] and  in range (0,T):
                J[T] = totalgrayvalue
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Calculate some sort of mean? Generate some sort of mask?

Comment: I'm trying to find all value of sigma when T go from 0 to 255. To do that I have to know "total gray value of pixels that have less gray value than T (T=0,T=1,...) ".  I'm curious are there still some commands to get pixel's gray value to work with.                                              Specific problem:  https://photos.app.goo.gl/wd5D7Q9iJDKpXQDH9

Comment: Ok, thank you. Surely you have a sample image?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post Sample image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/E4ogvjvHGknhZBcCA                Results image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/QMsG24rSiL9mmARE9

Answer (score 2):

Giving the complete answer would be no fun for you, so here are some thoughts and a little animation.

Using Python `for` loops with images is really not very advisable, they are slow and error-prone. Try to favour vectorised code like **Numpy** or **OpenCV** in general.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('Mushroom1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Calculate total number of pixels in image
nPixels = im.size

# Iterate over the possible threshold values, skipping 10 at a time for speed of development/checking
for T in range(1,255,10):
   # Make all pixels under threshold black, leaving those above threshold unchanged
   thresholded = (im < T) * im
   # Save the image for debug and animation
   cv2.imwrite(f'DEBUG-T{T:03}.png', thresholded)

   # Count the non-zero and deduce the zero pixels
   nonZero = cv2.countNonZero(thresholded)
   Zero = nPixels - nonZero

   # Sum the non-zero pixels
   sum = np.sum(thresholded)

   # Print some statistics
   print(f'T={T}, zero={Zero}, nonZero={nonZero}, sum={sum}')
```

[image]

---

**Sample Output**

```
T=1, zero=272640, nonZero=0, sum=0
T=11, zero=241004, nonZero=31636, sum=155929
T=21, zero=225472, nonZero=47168, sum=387872
T=31, zero=217889, nonZero=54751, sum=576313
T=41, zero=214256, nonZero=58384, sum=703371
T=51, zero=212088, nonZero=60552, sum=801384
T=61, zero=210347, nonZero=62293, sum=897791
T=71, zero=208741, nonZero=63899, sum=1002737
T=81, zero=206957, nonZero=65683, sum=1137514
T=91, zero=205196, nonZero=67444, sum=1288089
T=101, zero=203262, nonZero=69378, sum=1472991
T=111, zero=200945, nonZero=71695, sum=1717630
T=121, zero=198389, nonZero=74251, sum=2012972
T=131, zero=195386, nonZero=77254, sum=2390555
T=141, zero=191845, nonZero=80795, sum=2870781
T=151, zero=187409, nonZero=85231, sum=3517150
T=161, zero=181320, nonZero=91320, sum=4465922
T=171, zero=171610, nonZero=101030, sum=6076646
T=181, zero=156768, nonZero=115872, sum=8686503
T=191, zero=134692, nonZero=137948, sum=12787198
T=201, zero=105763, nonZero=166877, sum=18447591
T=211, zero=73061, nonZero=199579, sum=25171467
T=221, zero=42168, nonZero=230472, sum=31826825
T=231, zero=15384, nonZero=257256, sum=37855551
T=241, zero=5364, nonZero=267276, sum=40200454
T=251, zero=4926, nonZero=267714, sum=40306547
```

---

You might like to have a look at this code - just ignore the line numbers preceding the colon if you are unaccustomed to **IPython**, and be aware that it prints variables if you type their name:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: im = np.arange(7)
In [4]: im
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
In [5]: mask = im < 3
In [6]: mask
Out[6]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False])
In [7]: im[mask].sum()          # sum of values < 3
Out[7]: 3
In [8]: im[~mask].sum()         # sum of values >= 3
Out[8]: 18
```